# Rolling year extract

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table.With a date format of TO_CHAR(DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')

TableA

```
id        dt   
 1      20180101 
 2      20180201
 3      20170101
```

Is there a way to exttract a rolling year of data?

expected output:

```
id        dt   
 1      20180101 
 2      20180201
```

My SQL below: Which is not working...

```
select *
from tableA
where A.DT >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD') -365
```

Comment: TO_DATE is applied to strings. SYSDATE is not a string, it is a date. If you are lucky, you will get an error straight from that. Oracle is big brother though, and it will convert SYSDATE to a string and then back to a date... Anyway: What is the data type of the DT column? Is it number or varchar2? (AND: Why is it not `DATE`?)

Comment: Got it, I was able to solve by leaving date as date. I can post my answer when time allows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE TO_DATE(DT,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= SYSDATE -365
```

as `SYSDATE` is already a date you do not have to convert it into a `DATE`

Comment: Problem is, DT is not in `date` data type, so this won't help.

Comment: `TO_DATE(DT,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)` will work also for leap years.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I convereted date to string `ORA-01861: liter does not match format string` Create another column that does not convert TO_CHAR and them compare date to date.

id    dt           dt2
  1    20180101     01/01/2018

`where AND A.DT2 >= SYSDATE -365` will now work.